# How to upload a multiple APK in Playstore console

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-console

Here I can spilts APK by Android architecture in my build **gradle**. I am using a ndk **abiFilters** and spilt APK after generate/build release APK and getting 7 different-different APK of architecture.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.XXX.XXXXX"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v8a", "x86", "mips"
        }

        multiDexEnabled true
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath false
            }
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions "default"



    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi-v8a", "x86", "x86_64", "mips", "mips64"
            universalApk false
        }
    }
```

How to upload all that 7 different apk on playstore and how manage those all apks.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Steps of Upload multiple APKs to Google Console -**

1. Go to your google console and Fill all the compulsory data with one APK out of your 7 different APKs and submit the app for production.
2. Now go to **Create Release** in **App Release**.
3. Upload another APK and **Retain** the previous APK and submit the changes to production.
4. Repeat step 2 and 3 for the the APKs and don't forget to Retain the apk. If you don't do so then the apk will be lost.

> To update the App with new versions of Apks, Deactivate all the apk and repeat the steps.

Comment: thanks dude, this works. Last time I could upload all apks at once and now it does not work.

Comment: Hey @KebabKrabby, Google has updated the UI and the App upload process on the Google Play store. They have changed RETAIN to INCLUDE. And to update the new APKs, you need to REMOVE THE APK instead of Deactivate.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest now you can use Android app Build bundle. It will manage multiple devices which you are supports in your code.
*Reference link* 
https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle/

Still you want to upload multiple APK you must enable Advanced mode in your application's APK files tab. Once in advanced mode, you can upload, activate, then publish multiple APKs for the same application. 
*Reference link* https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks